# Adding BGTZ to One-Cycle MIPS CPU

Tags: alu, mips

I'm trying to add the MIPS assembly command BGTZ to the following circuit: [image]

I know that BGTZ takes the register value and sees if it's greater than 0. If it's greater it branches to the target. Can I compare the register value to a constant zero with an or gate?

EDIT: corrected BGTZ

Comment: BGTZ stands for Branch on Greater Than Zero, and applies to a single register. You are apparently thinking of BEQ.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast oh shoot you're right! So I can compare the register value to 0 and if it's greater have the branch trigger?

Comment: Sure. As long as you can find a command which does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to add BGTZ to the circuit: [image]